# How to generate the graph in R with different line in the same graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, confidence-interval

**How to generate the graph in R with different lines in the same graph??**
**for example** [image]
**1) first is dot line for observed data
2) second is continuous line for predicted data
3) third is the %range of CI (confidence interval)**

Comment: Add a new lawyer for each separate line that you want. Specify the x mapping in the overall ggplot call and the y mapping in the individual layers

Comment: What's about using information from web e.g. [Smoothed conditional means](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html). You'll find a lot of examples.

Comment: @PaulLemmens thank you; this 95%PPU gray line is with upper and lower values and the other two lines are with a single value, any shared example will be appreciable. best regards!

Comment: @help-info.de thank you; this 95%PPU gray line is with upper and lower values and the other two lines are with a single value, any shared example as you did, will be appreciable. best regards!

Comment: @SurajKumarBhagat If you have a reproducible example I can work out the details.

Comment: @PaulLemmens thanks! excuse me, I can not but any randomly generated data also would be appreciable.